# How to retain the value of 'me' when passing through another applescript

Tags: file, scripting, applescript

I have 2 applescripts... one called 'App' and one called 'Shell'. I want to be able to reference the name of the 'App' script within the 'Shell' script. What I've found so far is if the 'Shell' script reads anything with **me** in it, it seems to reference itself, instead of the 'App' script.

```
-- App.scpt

set appName to name of me


--Shell.scpt

tell application "System Events"
    
    set appScript to (load script file (POSIX file "/Path/To/App.scpt"))
    run appScript
    
    return appName
    
end tell
```

I've tried varying alternatives of what's written above with results such as errors, *missing values*, or 'Shell', which is incorrect... Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `me` always refers to the current script - perhaps you could explain _exactly_ what you are trying to do.

Comment: So maybe the example wasn't the best, was trying to keep it simple. If instead of 'name of me', I used the example 'path to me', hopefully my intent is clearer... If I have a sub script built which relies on paths relative to the sub script... ie using 'path to me', how can I get the main script which references the sub script to use those relative paths, and not turn them into paths relative to the main script?

Comment: The Script Editors can get in the way if you are using them to set the initial global/property values, so you might try using `osascript` in a `do shell script` statement to run the app.scpt before loading it.  Note that you do not need System Events to use the `load script` command.

Comment: What happens if you first coerce the name (or path) to text in the 'app' script?

Comment: Thanks for the response @red_menace. You're correct, system events in a tell block is not required, I'd left in error whilst trying to work something else out! Also, using osacript loads the app.scpt fine, but returning any variable from this is not as straight forward as the example I have above. If the variables don't rely on the 'name of me' function it seems to work fine, and I can call it as simply as if it was calling it directly within the app.scpt. However, if I run osascript on the app.scpt, and the only line of code in there is the 'name of me' function, it correctly return it.

Comment: @Mockman I can coerce the response, but it's still returning the name wrongly as 'shell' and not 'app'

Comment: When you load a script everything in it is available, including any previously set properties and global variables, so the use for `osascript` was to run the script with another AppleScript instance (different than the Script Editor) in order for it initialize some some of its properties/variables, after which you just use those values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term `me` always refers to the script that is currently being executed.  The `load script` command returns the specified compiled script as a script object, which is treated as if it were local, i.e. the same as if it were in the script that loaded it.

AppleScript has historically saved the values of script properties and globals in the script file itself (unless it has been made read-only), so that they will retain their values from the previous run.  When using the `load script` command, you have access to all the handlers and properties/global variables of that script.  The Script Editor can get in the way if you try to use it to set these initial values (as the script will be run locally), so you can use another AppleScript instance such as the Script Menu or `osascript` to run the app.scpt to set its initial values.  Personally, I would set up App.scpt to be more flexible by accepting command line arguments, and include an initialization handler to (re)set whatever desired values:

App.scpt:

```
# script containing properties/globals/handlers to be loaded by another script - initialized via command line

property myPath : missing value
property myName : missing value

global testing -- global variables can also be used

on run args -- arguments passed via command line
   if args is not {} then
      if (count args) is 1 and (args as text) is "init" then
         init()
      else
         -- handle any other CLI arguments
      end if
   end if
   -- other script stuff
end run

to init()
   set testing to "This is some testing text." & return & "Some testing text this is."
   set myPath to (path to me) -- alias
   set myName to (name of me)
   -- (re)set any other properties and/or global variables
end init

on testDialog(theTitle, theText)
   display dialog (theText as text) with title (theTitle as text) -- whatever
end testDialog
```

Shell.scpt:

```
# script to get get property/global values from a loaded script, initializing as needed

set scriptPath to POSIX path of (choose file) -- or wherever
set theScript to (load script scriptPath)
try
   if theScript's myPath is missing value then error "script was not initialized" -- check for a value
on error errmess
   log errmess
   do shell script "osascript " & quoted form of scriptPath & " init" -- initialize
   set theScript to (load script scriptPath) -- reload to get current values
end try

display dialog (theScript's myPath) as text with title (theScript's myName) -- display values from loaded script
tell theScript to testDialog("Test", theScript's testing) -- use handler in loaded script
```

Note that the `load script` command is from Standard Additions and scripts and applications have a `name` property, so you do not need to use System Events for those.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses and also supplying an answer which works, and will also help others in the same dilemma. I've marked your answer as correct, and will probably refer back to it when I hit a roadblock with my own answer... Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

After much consideration, I've decided to go down the following route, adding the additional 'path to me' command too for reference...

```
-- App.scpt

try
    set appName to scriptName
    set appPath to scriptPath
on error
    set appName to name of me
    set appPath to path to me
end try

    --> Insert rest of the script here <--


--Shell.scpt

set scriptPath to (posix file "/Path/To/App.scpt" as alias)
tell application "System Events" to set scriptName to name of scriptPath
run (load script file scriptPath)


    --> Insert rest of the script here <--
```

As the Shell.scpt will already know the path of the App.scpt (as it would need to load it) I've taken the easy option to reference this name and path instead.

The 'on error' statement in the App.scpt works by using the details from the Shell.scpt (if available) and if they're not available, reverts back to referencing the 'me' commands.

I can add many different App.scpt examples to this Shell.scpt using what I've outlined and everything should now work as intended, with variables being returned as they should, and 'me' commands being referenced correctly.

Comment: That seems to have the same issue as before - are you saving app.scpt after running it?

Comment: If I run the Shell.scpt, it will load the App.scpt and use the appName and appPath variables set in the Shell.scpt. This avoids the accidental use of the name and path of the Shell.scpt itself. However, if I need to test the App.scpt separate to the Shell.scpt, I can do, and the name and path variables revert back to the 'me' commands. This is all possible because of the 'on error' statement in the App.scpt. Hope this makes sense!

Comment: Unless you are running App.scpt and then saving it, or running it with another instance of AppleScript such as `osascript`, globals would not be saved in the file (the same as your original question), so I was wondering if that was how you were getting them to be saved.

Comment: Loading the App.scpt in the Shell.scpt via the 'load script file' command, ensures all variables within the App.scpt are passed on as if they were contained within the Shell.scpt itself. The only instances where this wasn't the case, was anything using the 'me' command, as this was returning the incorrect names/paths. The answer above works as intended. Although osascript would work in a contained environment, it doesn't help in this situation because the variables aren't carried over and would require all variables to be re-returned at the end of the App.scpt, and called out in the Shell.scpt

Comment: I understand that, it is just that shell.scpt in your answer is not getting anything from app.scpt, so I am trying to understand how it is working correctly.  Note that `osascript` just runs the script in a different AppleScript instance, everything is saved in the script as usual.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion... my request above was to only correctly retrieve the 'me' commands in order to run all the other commands, variables, statements etc in the App.scpt correctly. I've edited the above to hopefully show what I mean.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you are not getting anything from App.scpt -  `appPath` and `appName` are both from Shell.scpt.  Try adding another variable to App.scpt, such as `set myTest to "Testing"` and get it from Shell.scpt to see what I am talking about.

Comment: Setting your example variable in App.scpt, returns "Testing" correctly in the Shell.scpt if I type 'return myTest' at the end of the Shell.scpt. Yes, the appPath and appName are set in the Shell.scpt, because the Shell.scpt needs to know the path of the App.scpt in order to load it, so these 2 variables can be set from that. If the App.scpt runs independently, it will error at the first hurdle as the appPath and appName are not defined, causing it to trigger the name of me and path to me commands instead.

Comment: I see what you're doing now - you aren't using items in a loaded script, you are just having it return a value. I've posted an answer that uses properties, globals, and handlers in a loaded script.